# Replace variable texts with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, replace

I'm reformulating one of my old programs and using TextCrawler to automate text replacements in several code files, but I'm struggling to make the following change:

I need to find all 'text' functions (example):

```
$object->text('TRANSLATE_KEY_A')
$object->text('TRANSLATE_KEY_B')
...
```

and replace them with (example):

```
__('RETURNED_TEXT_FROM_TRANSLATE_KEY_A', TEXT_DOMAIN)
__('RETURNED_TEXT_FROM_TRANSLATE_KEY_B', TEXT_DOMAIN)
...
```

Where `RETURNED_TEXT_FROM_TRANSLATE_KEY_X` are set with the `'text'` array's key in another code file

```
array_push($text, array('key' => 'TRANSLATE_KEY_A',
                        'extras' => '',
                        'text' => 'Translated Text A'));

array_push($text, array('key' => 'TRANSLATE_KEY_B',
                        'extras' => '',
                        'text' => 'Translated Text B'));
```

The final result should be:

```
$object->text('TRANSLATE_KEY_A')
$object->text('TRANSLATE_KEY_B')
...
```

replaced with

```
__('Translated Text A', TEXT_DOMAIN)
__('Translated Text B', TEXT_DOMAIN)
...
```

There are over 1500 of these :(
Is it possible to achieve this with regular expression in TextCrawler, and how? Or any other idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a php array to provide the replacement data it is probably best to just use php itself for the task.

Example `script.php`:

```
// your $text array
$text = array();
array_push($text, array(
    'key' => 'TRANSLATE_KEY_A',
    'extras' => '',
    'text' => 'Translated Text A')
);
array_push($text, array(
    'key' => 'TRANSLATE_KEY_B',
    'extras' => '',
    'text' => 'Translated Text B')
);
...

// create a separate array from your $text array for easy lookup
$data_arr = array();
foreach ($text as $val) {
    $data_arr[$val['key']] = $val['text'];
}

// your code file, passed as first argument
$your_code_file = $argv[1];

// open file for reading
$fh = fopen($your_code_file, "r");
if ($fh) {
    while (($line = fgets($fh)) !== false) {
        // check if $line has a 'text' function and if the key is in $data_arr
        // if so, replace $line with the __(...) pattern
        if (preg_match('/^\$object->text\(\'([^\']+)\'\)$/', $line, $matches)
            && isset($data_arr[$matches[1]])) {
            printf("__('%s', TEXT_DOMAIN)\n", $data_arr[$1]);
        } else {
            print($line);
        }
    }
    fclose($fh);
} else {
    print("error while opening file\n");
}
```

Call:

```
php script.php your_code_file
```

Just add functionality to iterate over all of your code files and write to the corresponding output files.